# How to search all string in trie in C

Tags: c, string, trie

I inserted aroung 10k string to Trie and now I need to find 1 and compare with others and again for every single string. So this search should be fast and I don't think so that my function is the best solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "trie.h"
#include "lcs.h"

#define WORD_SIZE 64
#define CHAR_SIZE 256
#define FILE_NAME "file.txt"

char words[WORD_SIZE] = {0};
char defWord[WORD_SIZE] = {0};
int firstWord = 0;
int j = 0;

void searchStrings(struct Trie *head) {
struct Trie *curr = head;
int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < CHAR_SIZE - 1; i++) {
        if (curr->character[i] != NULL && !curr[i].isProcessed) {
            if (curr[i].isLeaf) {
                if (!firstWord) {
                    for (k = 0; k < WORD_SIZE; k++) {
                        defWord[k] = words[k];
                        if (words[k] == '\0') break;
                    }
                    firstWord = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                curr[i].isProcessed = 1;
                //compareStrings(words); TODO: complete that function
            } else {
                words[j] = i;
                searchStrings(curr);
            }
        }
    }
}

void parseData(FILE *text) {
    int c = 0, wordIter = 0;
    char word[WORD_SIZE] = {0};
    struct Trie *head = getNewTrieNode();

    if (!head) {
        printf("Error! Structure is not created.");
        return;
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    while (c != EOF) {
        c = getc(text);

        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            insert(&head, word);
            memset(word, 0, strlen(word));
            wordIter = 0;
            continue;
        }
        word[wordIter++] = c;
    }
    searchStrings(head);
    free(head);
}

int loadFile() {
    FILE *text;

    text = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    if (!text) {
        printf("Error! Cannot open file.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    parseData(text);

    fclose(text);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is trie's file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "trie.h"

#define CHAR_SIZE 256

struct Trie {
    int isLeaf;    // 1 when node is a leaf node
    int isProcessed; // 1 when leaf node is processed
    struct Trie *character[CHAR_SIZE];
};

// Function that returns a new Trie node
struct Trie *getNewTrieNode() {
    int i;
    struct Trie *node = (struct Trie *) malloc(sizeof(struct Trie));
    node->isLeaf = 0;
    node->isProcessed = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < CHAR_SIZE; i++)
        node->character[i] = NULL;

    return node;
}

// Iterative function to insert a string in Trie.
void insert(struct Trie **head, char *str) {
    // start from root node
    struct Trie *curr = *head;
    int numb = 0;

    while (*str) {
        numb = *str - 'A';

        if (numb < 0) { // for negative numbers
            numb += CHAR_SIZE;
        }
        // create a new node if path doesn't exists
        if (curr->character[numb] == NULL)
            curr->character[numb] = getNewTrieNode();

        // go to next node
        curr = curr->character[numb];

        // move to next character
        str++;
    }

    // mark current node as leaf
    curr->isLeaf = 1;
}
```

Main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"

int main(void) {

    loadFile();

    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for param isLeaf. If is param 1, it mean there is end of string. So when I find first char, which is not processed I can add it to global array. When I find first Leaf char I can save it and send it to next function. But there is problem with vowels. I can add if statement when length > 3. Can I make it easier? Or is there any better algo? There is 256 char size, because I need all chars of czech alphabet including capital letters and some chars are 128+ in CP1250 ascii.

Comment: You may need to think about 'isLeaf' a bit differently.  Suppose you have the (English) words: `star`, `stars`, `start`, `stare`, `started`, `starting`, `starring`, `staring`, `stared`, `starred`.  Then the node representing `star` is a word (on its own, it is a word), so you need a mechanism to mark that, but there are a whole lot of other words that also begin with `star` — so you have to be ready to move on to other words with letters such as `e`, `i`, `r`, `s`, `t`, some of which mark the end of a word, and some of which have more words continuing from them.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ So, `isLeaf` might perhaps be better named `isWord` or `WordEndsHere`, but you won't know until you've checked the 256 entries in the `character` array whether you've processed everything.  Alternatively, `isLeaf` does tell you whether any of the entries in `character` are non-null, but you need another flag in the code to mark the 'end of word' condition. Since there isn't an obvious "word ends here" marker, it's plausible that you've not fully dealt with it.

Comment: Also, and separately, do you have case-conversion problems?  Are all the upper-case and lower-case accented characters in CP 1250 the same distance apart as the upper-case and lower-case unaccented characters?  Should you be using `setlocale()` and `isalpha()` and/or `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()`, `tolower()`?